# Construct CSV file with TAGS

Tags: python, csv, tags

For the beginning, I need help with theoretical part of this. 
(If someone already faced this problem and have sample code, will be appreciated)

Imagine you have a product, for example, soap. Inside description will be a lot of tags(Inside text file).

```
line 1 productName:SOAP1, productCategory:Bath, productSubCategory: Soap, bla, bla, bla
line 2 productName:SOAP2, productCategory:Bath, productSubCategory: Soap, bla, bla, bla
line 3 productName:SOAP3, productCategory:Bath, productSubCategory: Soap, bla, bla, bla
```

Columns will all have **":"**

and I need to convert these tags to CSV which will look like this by using python code:

```
productName    productCategory    productSubCategory
  SOAP1             Bath                 Soap
  SOAP2             Bath                 Soap
  SOAP3             Bath                 Soap
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to do it.

Comment: Is there a fixed set of tags that you know in advance?

Comment: @AlexHall  There will be a lot of tags per product. the one which made for me will be with **"columnName:columnDescription"**, Ideally yes I will know in advanced column names which I need to use and will be inside tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
import csv

columns = ['productName', 'productCategory', 'productSubCategory']

with open('data.txt') as infile:
  with open('result.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in infile:
      row = {}
      for column in columns:
        pattern = column + ':(.+?)(, |$)'
        match = re.search(pattern, line)
        row[column] = match.group(1)
      writer.writerow(row)
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/AdmiredDefenselessQuote)

If you are not familiar with regexes, it's time to do some googling and reading.

This solution assumes that each item is of the form `<tag>:<value>` followed by either (1) a comma and a space (`", "`) or (2) the end of the line (represented by `$` in the regex).  If the value contains `", "`, the result will be incorrect. Any space after the `:` will be included in the value.

Comment: Forgot to say thank you, as it is nice and simple way

Answer (score 2):

This allows you to have dynamic headers.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'yourfile.txt',header=None)
print (df)
#                0                     1                         2
#productName:SOAP1, productCategory:Bath, productSubCategory: Soap
#productName:SOAP2, productCategory:Bath, productSubCategory: Soap
#productName:SOAP3, productCategory:Bath, productSubCategory: Soap

headerlist = []
for x in df.loc[0,:]:
    headerlist.append(x.split(':')[0])

for x in df.index:
    for y in df.columns:
        df.loc[x,y] = df.loc[x,y].split(':')[1]
df.columns = headerlist

print (df)
#  productName  productCategory  productSubCategory
#0       SOAP1             Bath                Soap
#1       SOAP2             Bath                Soap
#2       SOAP3             Bath                Soap
```

Comment: I had thought about using pandas, could you test your file with extra tags from left and right? this is a good method but hard to make it work right

Comment: @J.Doe Fixed the code, try it now. I missed out an `.index` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, you can use the `csv` module for both reading the input and writing the output file.

```
import csv

inp_filename = 'tagged.txt'
out_filename = 'csv_from_tagged.csv'

with open(inp_filename, 'r', newline='') as inp:
    line = next(inp)
    fieldnames = [elem.split(':')[0] for elem in line.split(',')]

    inp.seek(0)  # Rewind

    with open(out_filename, 'w', newline='') as outp:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(outp, fieldnames)
        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for row in csv.reader(inp):
            as_dict = dict(tuple(elem.split(':')) for elem in row)
            csv_writer.writerow(as_dict)

print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield)? It should be easier to store data in it. If not please look at the code below.

In step 1 it build a list of tags which I assume can be dynamic, and put it into first line. Further, it write csv file with data.
Hope it helps :)

```
import csv

text_area_value = 'productName:SOAP1, productCategory:Bath, productSubCategory: Soap, bla, bla, bla\nproductName:SOAP2, productCategory:Bath, productSubCategory: Soap, bla, bla, bla\nproductName:SOAP3, productCategory:Bath, productSubCategory: Soap, bla, bla, bla'

response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="data.csv"'
writer = csv.writer(response)

tagsList = []
for i, line in enumerate(text_area_value.split('\n')):
    dataList = []   
    if i == 0:
        #Getting the list of tags and the data from first line
        for tag in line.split(','):
            if ':' in tag:
                tagsList.append(tag.split(':')[0].replace(' ', ''))
                dataList.append(tag.split(':')[1].replace(' ', ''))
        writer.writerow(tagsList) # ok we've got list of tags in a first csv line now we can add rest of csv data
        writer.writerow(dataList) # CSV data - first line
    else:
        #Getting the data from every next line
        for tag in line.split(','):
            if ':' in tag:
                dataList.append(tag.split(':')[1].replace(' ', ''))
        writer.writerow(dataList) # CSV data

return response
```

Comment: IThank you for this, but this is overcomplicated method

Comment: No problem. :-)